# EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink C:\Users

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor 1.4.3.2 on a windows7 dev environment.

A Meteor application I have developed has been great for 6+ months but I have caused a problem by removing modules and apparently something I should not have.
Something outside the application folders (sym-link pointing into \AppData\Local.meteor.. somewhere) is missing/wrong, I think.

All other projects are fine, except this one.

All of my backup copies for this project are failing now too, including fresh clone from repo.
No 'meteor' commands will in this project, or it's backup copies, so 'meteor reset' is not an option.

The error is:

```
C:\Users\muser\iNotice>meteor
C:\Users\muser\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.3_2\mt-os.windows.
x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\muser\iNotice\.meteor\lo
cal\dev_bundle'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:932:18)
    at exports.makeLink (C:\tools\cli\dev-bundle-links.js:20:8)
    at [object Object]._.extend.ensureDevBundleLink (C:\tools\project-context.js
:1476:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._readFile (C:\tools\project-context.js:1410:10)
    at new exports.ReleaseFile (C:\tools\project-context.js:1360:8)
    at C:\tools\cli\main.js:898:22
```

Any suggestions on best approach to fix the application?

Thanks very much for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 5):

Pick one of the following:

- You can delete the content of your .meteor/local folder (repopulated next time you run > meteor)
- Or call meteor as an admin
- Or remove the read-only access on the dev_bundle folder (but Windows sets it back to read-only from time to time)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @n3squik!

Here are the actions I took which fixed my problem.

Remove folders:

```
C:\Users\muser\testApp\.meteor\local\dev_bundle*\*
C:\Users\muser\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\*
```

Ran:

```
C:\Users\muser\testApp> meteor run
```

The application started up and all seems good.

Thanks again Stack.